# Make a Child Div Extend to Browser Size

Tags: html, css, browser, height

I was wondering how to make a div with position:absolute extend to the bottom of the browser when it is the child of a div with position:relative. Here is the html:

```
<div id='square'>
<div id='rectangle' /></div>
```

And here is the css:

```
#square {
position:relative;
height:100px;
width:100px;
background:red;
}
#rectangle {
position:absolute;
width:50px;
background:blue;
height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mHpuW/

Comment: You'd have to remove `position:relative` from `#square`. And your HTML is invalid BTW.

Comment: Yea, not really possible to do this while keeping the parent relative.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mHpuW/1/

```
html,body{height:100%;}
#square {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
#rectangle {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the #rectangle to extend the full height.

Comment: You can put whatever height you wanna ... the only thing that matters is that if you want your <div> to have height: 100% working all the parent elements must have it too.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have resolved the issue another way.